# Why am I getting different results from ng-show="!emptyArray" and ng-hide="emptyArray"?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have always thought `ngShow` and `ngHide` act as boolean counterpart to each other. That belief, however, is shaken by the unexpected behaviour of `ngShow` when an empty array is involved.

Here is a [demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5dHtHRdxUuYueOVYGmJ0?p=preview). Why isn't `ng-show="!emptyArray"` behaving like `ng-hide="emptyArray"`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Because `[] !== false`. You can coerce the length value to `boolean` instead with `!!`.

```
<div ng-hide="!!emptyArray.length">emptyArray is falsy, so do not hide this.</div>
<div ng-show="!!!emptyArray.length">!emptyArray is truthy, so show this.</div>
```

Edited:

AngularJS's directive `hide` or `show` depends on the function `toBoolean()` for evaluating the value passed in. Here is the source code of [toBoolean()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L835):

```
function toBoolean(value) {
  if (value && value.length !== 0) {
    var v = lowercase("" + value);
    value = !(v == 'f' || v == '0' || v == 'false' || v == 'no' || v == 'n' || v == '[]');
  } else {
    value = false;
  }
  return value;
}
```

And you can verify the following code in JS console:

```
>var emptyArray = [];
>toBoolean(emptyArray)
false
>toBoolean(!emptyArray)
false
```

That explains why. Since when `emptyArray` is passed to the `toBoolean()` directly, it evaluates the correct result `false`. However when `!emptyArray` is passed to `toBoolean()`, it doesn't evaluate to `true` since `!emptyArray` is `false` itself.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `ng-hide="someArray"` works as expected, regardles `someArray.length` is zero or greater than zero. My concern here is on the behaviour pattern difference between `ngShow` and `ngHide`. `ngHide` seems to work fine without explicitly using `length` but not in the case of `ngShow`.

Answer (score 5):

**ng-if and ng-show mistreats "[]" (empty array)**

See: this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3969)

```
[] == true
false

 [] != true
 true

(![]) == true
false

[''] == true
false

(!['']) == true
false

"" == true
false

"[]" == true
false

(!"[]") == true
false
```

Sounds its by design.

Comment: but `emptyArray` is defined as `[]`. See the attached plunker.

Comment: My question is not so much about the how. I am looking for the rationale behind the behaviour difference between `ng-hide="someArray"` and `ng-show="!someArray"`. `ngHide` seems to work perfectly regardless `someArray` is empty or not. But I don't see the same for `ngShow`.

Comment: see my description I posted, + link

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this , it works to me

```
ng-hide="array.length == 0"
```