# directive scope rewrite parent value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote directive:

```
   ensureUnique: function ($http, $parse) {
        return {
            scope: {
                ensureUniqueType: "=",
                ensureUniqueDisabled: "="
            },
         ...
        }
    },
```

but if i try use it like this:

```
<input name = "groupId" ng-show="anyFunction()" 
       type="text" ng-model="group.groupId" 
       ensure-unique="" ensure-unique-disabled="oldId != '-1'" ensure-unique-type="type" >
```

the input element became invisible(does not depend on anyFunction result). It seems that directive scope rewrite ngShow value

Comment: That should actually give you an error when compiling about ensureUniqueDisabled not being an assignable expression.  You are using `ensureUniqueDisabled: '='`, but the `=` type of binding is made for assignable values.

You are looking for an expression, which is an `&` binding.

Look at the [directive guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and ctrl-f search for '&', then read about it.

You want to have `ensureUniqueDisabled: '&'` because you just have an expression, not an assignable model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do `ng-show="$parent.anyFunction()"` since the directive creates a new scope.

The reason why it is invisible is because since the function `anyFunction()` is `undefined`, `undefined` will be evaluated to `false` by the function `toBoolean()` in `ng-show` directive. You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19035489/304319) for the detail.