# found a bug for angularjs ng-show ng-if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found several bugs for angularjs:

```
<div ng-show="['[]']">this should be show but actually not</div>
<div ng-show="[]">this should be show but actually not</div>
<div ng-show="[0]">this should be show but actually not</div>
<div ng-show="['0']">this should be show but actually not</div>
```

when these criteria are used in the `if` statement in javascript, they are treated as true.
But in `ng-show`, `ng-hide`, `ng-if`, it is not working correctly.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Why would you use an array in place of a boolean?

Comment: Empty arrays evaluate to false in Angular expressions by design. See [Why am I getting different results from ng-show="!emptyArray" and ng-hide="emptyArray"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035406/why-am-i-getting-different-results-from-ng-show-emptyarray-and-ng-hide-empty)

Comment: The api doc for angularjs only tells truthy or falsy. I think it means only just true or false.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All of the statements above are invalid statements. I will give you examples.

```
 //What you have done here  is created an array with a string of '[]' which has no expression to return true or false;
<div ng-show="['[]']">this should be show but actually not</div>

// Here is just an empty array again with no expression to return true or false. Better use would be myArray.length > 0 which will evaluate as true or false;
<div ng-show="[]">this should be show but actually not</div>

 //Here is just like the first one except you have an array of one number being 0 which will still never evaluate to a true or false;
<div ng-show="[0]">this should be show but actually not</div>

 //I dont think this one needs any explaining as you can see the pattern from above;
<div ng-show="['0']">this should be show but actually not</div>
```

You are not using ng-show/if properly. You always need an expression that can evaluate true or false, or a function that will return true or false. Don't equate your angular in the html to your javascript.